# AWS codepipeline cloning issues

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have been trying to create CI/CD using code deploy and bitbucket repo.
The pipeline is successful but I am not seeking any codes into ec2. I can only see the node module in ec2.
If anyone came through the same issues or could help me to solve them that would be great.

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/gt
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      runas: root
```

start_server.sh

```
sudo apt-get update
# install the application using npm
# we need to traverse to where the application bundle is copied too.
#some comments
#added commets
sudo su
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/gt
mkdir /home/ubuntu/gt
echo installing application with npm
cd /home/ubuntu/gt
sudo apt-get install -y npm
echo installing pm2
npm install pm2 -g
sudo yarn
pm2 delete gt
pm2 start npm --name 'gt' -- start
```

Comment: I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, but not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting helpful answers is not only good practice, but reduces the number of duplicate questions and removes your question from the [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Unanswered&tagMode=Watched) list.

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Any progress or still fully unresolved?

Comment: @Marcin thank you for your answer. It was helpful to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not seeking any codes into ec2

This could be because you are **removing all content** of your folder:

```
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/gt
```

since your `ApplicationStart` runs after `files`. So whatever you copy in `files`, gets deleted in `ApplicationStart`. For the order of execution, please have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-server).